# slidify lectureSite: workflow and customizations

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidify

I am getting started with http://slidify.github.io/lectureSite/. I like the idea and the template very much. However, being new to this, I am struggling with customization.

Let me first explain what this 'lectureSite' architecture offers. The main code is based on `rmarkdown` and `slidify` and the customizations of the layout are mainly controlled in `css` files. The 'lectureSite' consists of an `html` webpage that serves as a contents page and starting point to access different slides ('lectures'), much of it created automagically. It looks as great as it sounds!

Each lecture is stored in a separate directory with its own 'assets' directory. So in a course made of 10 lectures, one has 10 directories, each with its own `css` and `js`. However, to achieve a common style for the whole course, one would like most of the customizations to be shared among all the lectures. My main problem is how to deal with this.

**Question:  How should I deal with the `css` customizations that I would like to share among all the lectures?**

I have been successful in customizing each lecture by inserting the css code into each `rmarkdown` file between `<style>` and `</style>` tags, but now I would like to take the customizations to a place where they may be shared. I expected that by including a `slidify.css` file inside `assets/css` the styles would be picked up, but they are not: could I be doing something wrong or was my expectation incorrect to begin with? And besides, there are so many of those `assets/css` directories that it would be tedious to have to copy the css into each every time it is modified. Is there a mechanism to set a single css file that would override the css inside `assets/css`?

I also tried to make a 'declaration' at the top of the rmarkdown file (something I saw there: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) with:

```
css         : slidify.css
```

but that gave the following error message:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch slidify.css
slidify.css: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Execution halted
```

An alternative would be to `source()` a text file with the customization between `<style>` and `</style>` tags. Are there any disadvantages to this approach? And btw what is the code for sourcing an external file from rmarkdown?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the 'lectureSite' template provides several independent templates and each one has to be compiled independently (contrary to my impression that a single compilation would recreate the whole structure), and each 'lecture' has its own ``css`` directory, and there is no ``centralization`` of styles at the root (as far as I could tell from limited testing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following structure:

```
assets      -> put custom img/js/css/layout assets
lectures    -> folder containing lectures
  Lecture 01
  Lecture 02
  Lecture 03
libraries   -> frameworks, highlighters and widgets
index.Rmd   -> Rmd source for home page
site.yml    -> Site related configuration
```

and suppose you are inside one of the Lectures `index.Rmd` files. I found the following seems to 'by-pass' the local assets directory to source the 'root' directory instead:

```
url         : {lib: "../../libraries", assets: "../../assets"}
```

If you place your css files into "../../assets/css/custom.css", that is the 'master' assets directory at the top of the structure (at the root, to say it differently), then it will be sourced by `slidify`. I deleted all the other assets directories and didn't find it did any harm (all they contained to begin with was one single file `ribbons.css`). Not extensively tested, but it worked on Firefox and Chrome.

In this way, I can have a single customization `css` for all the chapters.

However, this structure appears to work only for the `html5slides` framework and not for `io2012`.  For `io2012` I explain here what I did (it worked for me, but I have no idea if it's the right way):

https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/409

Somewhat more involved. Hopefully future versions of slidify will make it easier. One problem with dumping style files into the root assets directory is that, with the `html5slides` framework, all files are sourced. So my idea of having framework-specific css files in the assets directory doesn't work, because the styles are all sourced and some overwrite one another. So keeping the custom css files in framework-specific directories is probably a better approach anyhow.

I also found the following way of sharing `R` customizations and `knit opts` (or whatever they're called)

````
```{r 'preamble', message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, echo = FALSE, tidy = FALSE, comment = NA, cache = FALSE}  # probably several redundant ones in there
require(knitr) 
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, cache = FALSE)  # example of knit options
source('../../shared/shared.R')  # here I share common R code 
```
````